# Existe alguna API de facebook para traer informacion del usuario?

Tags: facebook

Estoy haciendo una pagina donde en el perfil del usuario hay un icono de github que al tocarlo te permite ingresar tu nombre de usuario de github y despues al volver a tocar el icono te redirige a su perfil de github. Esto fue facil por la api de github (`https://api.github.com/users/{{insert user}}`), que trae toda la informacion necesaria para esto.

Mi pregunta es si existe algo así para facebook, porque por lo que vi la url de facebook es algo asi `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1594722173` y la idea es que el usuario ingrese su email y ya le permita redirigirse a su perfil de facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Si existe debes registrar si gustas una cuenta nueva o usar la tuya de facebook. aca el link: [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Dependiendo del lenguaje que gustes hay apis, por ejemplo para js, python, etc. Pues no especificas el lenguaje.